# Access List Item Attachment outside SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, apple-ios, adal

I am developing iOS app using SharePoint Online data.

1. First I register app on Azure
2. Then I have given delegated permission where I have give Read
   permission to the site and web
3. Then I am generating token through Microsoft Azure Active Directory
   Authentication Library (ADAL) for iOS, It is generating token
   smoothly.
4. I am passing this token to in header for REST API call for
   SharePoint Online. Now I am getting data properly.

Now situation is that one of the filed of the SharePoint Online custom list is rich text which have Text and Images. Now my question is can I access image path in web viewer outside SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you getting Rich Text value programmatically it is HTML formated text, often started with DIV. So inside the  tag should be source url.